# How to add click event to element in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like the following

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', '']);

app.directive('myNav', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "directives/directive-test.html",
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //I want to add click event listen to li element
               element.on('mousedown', function(){
                    alert('test') //works on all ul but not individual li
                })
        }
    };
})
```

directive-test.html

```
<ul>
    <li class='nav-btn' ng-click='open()'>
        //contents
    </li>
    <li class='nav-btn' ng-click='open()'>
        //contents
    </li>
    <li class='nav-btn' ng-click='open()'>
        //contents
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure how to find the li element and assign a click event inside my directive.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `ng-click` already on the `<li>`? That's the "angular" way of handling click events.

Comment: Agreed with @dnc253.  You already have `ng-click` on the `<li>`s so it's overkill to add another listener.  If you need to differentiate between `<li>`s in the `open` function, try passing a different identifier (e.g. `ng-click="open(id)"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create something resembling accordion menu check out ui-bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion.

If not, why not just provide an argument to open() so you know which element was clicked (you can use $index if you need ng-repeat).

```
<ul>
    <li class='nav-btn' ng-click='open(0)'>
        //contents
    </li>
    <li class='nav-btn' ng-click='open(1)'>
        //contents
    </li>
    <li class='nav-btn' ng-click='open(2)'>
        //contents
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now scope.open will know which element was clicked. Or with ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-btn" ng-repeat="el in navElems" ng-click="open($index)">
        {{el.contents}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where navElems would be an array of objects, for example:

```
scope.navElems = [
  { contents: "link1" },
  { contents: "link2" },
  { contents: "link3" }
];
```

And an example open function:

```
scope.open = function(index) {
  var el = navElems[index];
  // do stuff with el
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', '']);

app.directive('myNav', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/directive-test.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.find('li').on('mousedown', function(){
                alert('test') 
             });
        }
    };
})
```